# Pie chart selectable per day

Tags: python, python-3.x, plotly

I have a data frame with 3 columns, name of a used application [‘app’], the time spend on this application [‘usage’] and a column with the date [‘date’]

I would like to make a Pie chart which is selectable per day.

I have got the following:

```
Fig6 = go.Figure(data=[go.Pie(labels=df4['app'], values=df4['usage'], hole=.3)])
```

together with

```
html.Div([
dcc.Graph(id='diagram6', figure=fig6)] , className='six columns')], className="row" )])
```

This makes a pie chart of all the data, but i would like to make it [‘date’] specific so it show the app and usage per day and is selectable with arrow buttons of something like that.

EDIT: 
The dataframe looks like this:

```
date        app                                                  usage

2019-05-26  app03                                                2.0
2019-05-26  app02                                                60.0
2019-05-26  app01                                                14.0

2019-05-27  app02                                                6.0
2019-05-27  app01                                                2.0

2019-05-28  app05                                                12.0
2019-05-28  app04                                                702.0
2019-05-28  app01                                                15.0
```

The date is flexible it can be other dates then above

Is this possible, and if can somebody help me with it?

Kind Regards

Comment: Can you show us, what the data looks like?

Comment: done, see above

Comment: So to understand you correctly, you have a date(selected by the user) and you only want to show the data for all apps for that particular day? You can simple filter the data to match the date with the selected user date. Like this filteredData = data.filter(entry => entry.date.isSameDay(selectedData)), of course you would have to write a function to compare the both dates to see if they are the same day.

Comment: Something like that indeed, that i can switch a pie digram per day.
But i never know which days are in the data (a maximum of 10) so is it possible that there is automicly made per date and i can switch thru them?

Comment: what language do you use and show me how you save the selected date.

Comment: I Use python and dash, the dates are stored in a format as above so yyyy-mm-dd

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197085/discussion-between-metroll-and-domino987).